# Access "Runtime error 3464" Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: ms-access, vba

Upon clicking a drop down menu and section of an entry that I have put in there, I get runtime error 3464 which is data type mismatch and stops at Set rsrecall = dbsrecall.OpenRecordset(strSQLWork)

What am I missing here?

```
Dim dbsrecall As DAO.Database
Dim rsrecall As DAO.Recordset
Dim intRecCnt As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_Click

strSQLWork = "SELECT tblAB.ID, .,.(lots)...., FROM tblAB WHERE tblAB.Title = " & Me.cmbGetRecall & " ORDER BY tblAB.CreationDate, tblAB.SolutionTarget, tblAB.StartDate;"

Set dbsrecall = CurrentDb()
Set rsrecall = dbsrecall.OpenRecordset(strSQLWork)

rsrecall.MoveFirst

ReDim arrRecall(1, 70)

arrRecall(1, 1) = rsrecall!abc
arrRecall(1, 2) = rsrecall!def
.
.(contd.)
.
arrRecall(1,70) = rsrecall!xyz

Me.txtTitle.SetFocus
Me.lblRecall.Visible = False
Me.cmbGetRecall.Visible = False

Me.txtqwe = arrRecall(1, 4)
Me.txtrty = arrRecall(1, 5)
Me.txtuio = arrRecall(1, 6)
.
.(contd.)  
.
me.txtghj = arrRecall(1,70)

Exit Sub
Err_Click:
resp = MsgBox("No records were found for this selection." & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & "Please try again.", vbOKOnly)

Me.cmbSol = ""
Me.cmbSol.SetFocus
```

Comment: At first glance, I don't see an issue. Do you have 'Option Explicit' at the top of your module?  If not, add that and then compile to see if you get any errors.

Comment: I do have Option Explicit. I have the same arrRecall logic in a different part of the project, is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
strSQLWork = " SELECT tblAB.ID, .,.(lots)...., FROM tblAB " & _
                      " WHERE tblAB.Title = '" & Me.cmbGetRecall & "'" & _
                      " ORDER BY tblAB.CreationDate, tblAB.SolutionTarget, tblAB.StartDate;"
```

Comment: Alright that one seems to be replaced by this now: Runtime Error 3021: No current record at rsrecall.Movefirst

Comment: RESOLVED:

    ...WHERE tblAB.Title = " & Me.cmbGetRecall & "  ORDER BY....

Thank you for your help guys